# ES6 syntax : what is this an error : .catch(err => throw err);

Tags: javascript

The following code works FINE:

```
 pool.getConnection()
    .then((conn)=>{
         // something here
       })
      .catch((err) => {
      throw err;
    });
```

However node throws error when I reformat it as such:

```
return pool.getConnection()
    .then((conn) => {
     //something here
    })
    .then(results => results[0].insertId)
    .catch(err => throw err);  <-- NODE COMPALINS HERE


$>somefile.js line(190)
.catch(err => throw err);
                  ^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token throw
```

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An arrow function has a behavior where, if you don't put `{}` after it, it has an implicit `return`.

So your code is essentially this:

```
.catch(err => { return throw err; });
```

You can only return expressions, and cannot return statements like `throw`.

```js
function test(e) {
  return throw e; // syntax error
}
```